# Extract the doctor name from given text in regex(re.findall) in python

Tags: python, regex

I have

```
text = 'he is Dr. alex dams. He puts up in Washington town since 1990. He has been a very good friend of Dr. kane Andeas and his family'
```

I want to get the following output using `re.findall`:

`['Dr. alex dams', 'Dr. kane Andeas']`

I am using the following code but just getting `['Dr.']` in output.

```
re.findall("Dr.[a-z\s]+",text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While PacketLoss answer works it will not catch hyphen divided names (like Pearl-Hopson or similar).

I would go for:

```
text = 'he is Dr. alex dams. He puts up in Washington town since 1990. He has been a very good friend of Dr. kane Andeas and his family'

re.findall(r'(Dr\.\s\S+\s\S+\b)', text)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the doctors will always follows the same format, you can search for then with `\w+` for a word and `\s` for space.

```
(Dr\.\s\w+\s\w+)
```

Code

---

```
text = 'he is Dr. alex dams. He puts up in Washington town since 1990. He has been a very good friend of Dr. kane Andeas and his family'

re.findall(r'(Dr\.\s\w+\s\w+)', text)

#['Dr. alex dams', 'Dr. kane Andeas']
```

Comment: Another alternative: `re.findall(r'(Dr\.(?:\s\w+){2})', text)` -- not really that much more succinct but could generalize easier

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you help me with one more thing, how can i extract a numerical string of 10 digits (exact 10 digits) in re.findall ? like i don't want other strings that have more than 10 digits and their 10 digits are shown in output. i just want strings of exact 10 digits.

Comment: `[0-9]{10}` you can use this

Comment: but this also gives the string which have more than 10 digits and the first 10 digits of those strings are also given in output.

Comment: You would need to open a new question with an example for that. There is not enough detail here to provide an answer.

Comment: You will need to raise a new question for this.